# Can we use values fetched from database table in XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, database, xslt

I have a database with me consisting of certain tables. I have written a query to fetch some fields from a table and stored those fetched values in some variables. Now, I am looking for a way which will allow to assign values fetched from database to the XSL variables. I am trying to generate a HTML page using fetched values.

Does anyone knows about how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: XSLT is an XML stylesheet, so your data really needs to be XML.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for information on the extensions some XSLT processors have for performing RDBMS operations.

Comment: Do note that with standar XSLT you can access any XML tree referenced by URI (as long as processor knows the protocol), as example: A REST response from database server to an XQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi @Vijay,**

**XSLT** *(Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations)* is an XML stylesheet which in simple terms means that it's used to fetch data from an XML file.

You'll need to generate an XML file/string with the results from your database and then use XSLT to query the XML file.

**[Umbraco](http://umbraco.org)** is an open-source CMS system which does exactly that. On every content publish, it generates an XML file with the most up-to-date data and then XSLT is used to generate HTML pages from that data.

Technically speaking, you could pull your database tables into a DataSet and then you can create an XML file from it which you can run your XSLT against.

**[This post](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ado_net/MappingDataSetToXMLAndBackwards.aspx)** explains how to do exactly that.

Have a read there and come back with any questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks Marko. Yes, XSLT is for XML, but I was not sure that if it works with databases as well. My doubt is  clear now. Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 1):

The W3c soecifications for XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 do not provide functionality for performing RDBMS operations.

**Some processors have extensions to do this**.

For example **Saxon has the following** [***extension elements***](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/sql-extension/intro.xml): `sql:connect`, `sql:query`, `sql:insert`, `sql:column`, `sql:update`, `sql:delete`, and `sql:close`

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. May be I should try this.